# CalendarService from google java client library doesn't have methods described in the tutorial

Tags: java, api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to do some work with Google Calendar on Java.
So I have read [the guide](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) and downloaded [client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list). I have added to my project gdata-calendar-2.0.jar and gdata-client-1.0.jar from the downloaded archive.

And now, according to the documentation, I should be able to do somethink like that:

```
// Create a CalenderService and authenticate
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("jo@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

But I can't. There is no such method "setUserCredentials". Actualy there are no other mehods, mentioned in documenation. I have decompiled CalendarService and here are all methods it have:

```
public CalendarService(java.lang.String applicationName)
public CalendarService(java.lang.String applicationName, com.google.gdata.client.Service.GDataRequestFactory requestFactory, com.google.gdata.client.AuthTokenFactory authTokenFactory)
public CalendarService(java.lang.String applicationName, java.lang.String protocol, java.lang.String domainName)

public java.lang.String getServiceVersion()
public static com.google.gdata.util.Version getVersion()
private void declareExtensions()
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setUserCredentials` is inherited from [`GoogleService`](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService.java), which [`CalendarService`](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/calendar/CalendarService.java) is a subclass of.

However, you're looking at the 2.0 documentation, but you say you've downloaded the **1.0** client jar file. Perhaps that's the problem? From the [gdata-java-client home page](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/):

> **Where is Version 2 of the Google Data Java Client Library?**
>
> Users of the previous version 2.2 of the gdata-java-client library should be able to easily upgrade to google-api-java-client version 1.0. Thus, the new library should be backwards compatible with version 2.2 (with a few rare exceptions). Version 2 of the gdata-java-client won't be developed any further, and all ongoing development will instead now continue in the new project. Summary: same library, but with additional features, and a new name.

I suggest you either build from the source of 1.43 (which definitely *does* include `setUserCredentials`) or start using [the new project](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) (which is admittedly still in alpha).

(Note: I work for Google, but this answer shouldn't be treated as being authoritatively "from" Google at all. I haven't had much to do with GData, and don't have any "inside information".)